# Deployment of web service work on local machine but on another machine throws runtime error

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7, web-deployment

I have made a web service which is working well on my local machine.

On another machine it shows wsdl and description of methods when url is on remote machine

ipaddress is : 192.168.6.51

http:// ipaddress /GPCB/GPCBWebService.asmx

but when we enter url on remote machine

http:// ipaddress /GPCB/GPCBWebService.asmx/GetIndustryList

it throws runtime error on remote machine .but on local machine it runs well...

What can be the solution

The Code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using Gpcb_ecModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for GPCBWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://GPCB/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment     the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class GPCBWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
SqlConnection cn = new     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Gpcb_ecConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    Gpcb_ecEntities gpcb1 = new Gpcb_ecEntities();
    public GPCBWebService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string About() {
    return "GPCB";
    }

    [WebMethod(Description = "Get List of industries with all the fields")]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetFullIndustryList()
    {
        List<tbl_Industry_Registration> indlist = new             List<tbl_Industry_Registration>();
        indlist = gpcb1.tbl_Industry_Registration.ToList();

    tbl_Industry_Registration[] indarray = new     tbl_Industry_Registration[indlist.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < indlist.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        indarray[i] = new tbl_Industry_Registration
        {
            Category_Id=indlist[i].Category_Id,
            Category_Type=indlist[i].Category_Type,
            District_Id=indlist[i].District_Id,
            EmailID=indlist[i].EmailID,
            Estate_Name=indlist[i].Estate_Name,
            GIDC_Area=indlist[i].GIDC_Area,
            GPCB_Id=indlist[i].GPCB_Id,
            Industry_Name=indlist[i].Industry_Name,
            IndustryId=indlist[i].IndustryId,
            Mobile_No=indlist[i].Mobile_No,
            Owner_Group=indlist[i].Owner_Group,
            Pan_Id=indlist[i].Pan_Id,
            Password=indlist[i].Password,
            Pincode=indlist[i].Pincode,
            Plot_No=indlist[i].Plot_No,
            Postal_Address=indlist[i].Postal_Address,
            Project_Cost=indlist[i].Project_Cost,
            Project_Location=indlist[i].Project_Location,
            Survey_No=indlist[i].Survey_No,
            Taluka_Id=indlist[i].Taluka_Id,
            Username=indlist[i].Username,
            Village_Id=indlist[i].Village_Id
        };
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(indarray, Formatting.Indented);
}

[WebMethod(Description = "Get List of industries with fileds industry id and industry name")]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetIndustryList()
{
    List<tbl_Industry_Registration> indlist = new List<tbl_Industry_Registration>();
    indlist = gpcb1.tbl_Industry_Registration.ToList();

    Industry[] indarray = new Industry[indlist.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < indlist.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        indarray[i] = new Industry
        {
            IndustryId = indlist[i].IndustryId,
            IndustryName = indlist[i].Industry_Name
        };
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(indarray);
    return strJSON;
    //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(indarray, Formatting.Indented);
}
public class Industry
{
    public int IndustryId { get; set; }
    public string IndustryName {get;set;}
}
}
```

error is

Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetIndustryList'

Please provide me solution...

Comment: It shows runtime error on remote machine

Comment: So, we should just guess what the error says then?

Comment: Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. T

Comment: It might be worth doing what it says to get the 'actual' error, and look in the event log on the machine.

Comment: 2014-03-11 10:01:11 192.168.6.51 POST /GPCB/GPCBWebService.asmx/About - 80 - 192.168.6.51 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 200 0 0 123
2014-03-11 10:02:27 192.168.6.51 GET /GPCB/GPCBWebService.asmx/GetIndustryList - 80 - 192.168.6.25 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 500 0 0 219

Comment: on remote machine it is showing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved....

I added following lines in Web.config file

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

and  it started working..

Comment: fixed my problem too!! thanks!!!